# JSON fetch dosen't work correctly in real host but work in localhost

Tags: php, android, android-volley, host

I have this `json` in my free host : http://alibhm.epizy.com/fetch_turbine2.php

As you seen fetching work correctly if run this in browser and fetch two parameter . But when put this url in my android app (with volley)  don't fetch anything . In previous when I use this json in my localhost(xampp) everything work correctly but when going to free host this problem appeared

**dbconfig.php**

```
<?php
//Define your host here.
$servername = "xxx";
//Define your database username here.
$username = "xxx";
//Define your database password here.
$password = "*******";
//Define your database name here.
$dbname = "xxx";
?>
```

**fetch_turbine2.php**

```
<?php 

include 'dbconfig.php';

$con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
 //creating a query
 $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT POWER , ONE_THRUST_BEARING_METAL_TEMP

 FROM turbine_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");

 //executing the query 
 $stmt->execute();

 //binding results to the query 
 $stmt->bind_result($t1,$t2);

 $boiler = array(); 

 //traversing through all the result 
 while($stmt->fetch()){
 $temp = array();

$temp['t1'] = $t1;
$temp['t2'] = $t2;

 array_push($boiler, $temp);
 }

 //displaying the result in json format 
 echo json_encode($boiler);
 ?>
```

**java**

```
StringRequest stringRequest1=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,"http://alibhm.epizy.com/fetch_turbine2.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray array=new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject product=array.getJSONObject(i);

                            String b1=product.getString("t1");
                            String b2=product.getString("t2");

                            final TextView a1=findViewById(R.id.pf1);
                            final TextView a2=findViewById(R.id.pf2);

                            a1.setText(b1);
                            a2.setText(b2);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest1);
```

Comment: Did you debug it? Did  the json string come from the request?

Comment: Debug to see what response string you are getting, from there you may get some idea what is going wrong

Comment: you mean debug in android studio? which part of logcat show that ?

Comment: i think my problem is from my host but why? i don't know . because it worked correctly in my localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after one week i found answer :) my code don't have problem . everything  cause by some free hosting protection . some free hosting have protection against bots . and my app known as bot for this host . i change my host and everything work like charm :) . i recommend use paid hosts to pass problems.